# Swift: Setting Email Recipients in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to add a choice to my `UIActivityViewController` to allow my users to send an email to every single one of their contacts. Assuming I have an algorithm to get all of the user's contacts' emails, how can I now assign those email addresses to the recipient value of a UIActivityViewController's email sharing?

Bonus Challenge: How can I make this a seperate option from the standard email? (Having both email with no recipients and email with all recipients in my `UIActivityViewController`)